# Click on <a> element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have problems activating a simple  element in HTML via JavaScript.

So I have a simple Setup:

```
<a href="example.com">
</a>

<button>Klick</button>
```

Now I want, that if the button is clicked, some JS Code will be executed, which then "Clicks" the  element. Similar to executing the .click() function on a button.

I also use jQuery, if that makes it easier for you. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

native Js has a [`click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) method on every elements, you just need to call it

```js
let button = document.getElementById("button")
let link = document.getElementById("link")

button.onclick = () => link.click()
```

```html
<a id="link" href="example.com"></a>
<button id="button">Klick</button>
```

---

if your objective is only to have a link looking like a button then using css is better than having 2 elements

as a bonus it allow you to keep all of the `<a>` default behavior you might lose by using a button

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  padding: 2px 25px;
  border: 1px solid #b6b6b3;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #e0e0df;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}
```

```html
<a href="example.com">I'm a &lt;a&gt;</a>
<button>I'm a &lt;button&gt;</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, I used the jQuery click() function. After "casting" to a normal DOM element by taking the variable and adding a [0] behind it, it works fine now,

Comment: @TimerErTim don't forget to mark the answer as accepter ;)